# Short story called "Daddy needs shorts", baby unconsciously saves his father from electrocution

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is seen from the point of view of a baby who only vaguely understands what is happening, but who saves his father from electrocution by creating a 'short' in the electricity. The lead-up, from a statement by the father that he needs a new pair of shorts, to the ending, takes many steps.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: Are you looking to find a copy to purchase/read online? Usually the [tag:story-identification] tag is for when you _don't_ know the title...

Comment: @FreeMan sometimes folks remember the title but cannot find the story because they lack the author (and the title is generic), and sometimes it's because they misremember the title (as the asker did here). Both of those are equally valid as story-id questions, we've have some of these before.

Comment: Is there anything in the story that is sci fi or fantasy?

Answer (score 21):

"Poppa Needs Shorts" (1964) by Walt and Leigh Richmond, available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/29789/29789-h/29789-h.htm).

> Shorts are useful. They help electrics to work harder.
> Shorts you wear, and they are electrics.
> Wires are electrics.
> Shorts can be made by juice.
> Shorts can be made by neatles, that bite like teeth.
> **Poppa needs more shorts.**

---

Found by browsing the Internet Science-Fiction Database for "needs shorts" ([query link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Needs+shorts&type=Fiction+Titles)).

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: Is there anything SFF about this?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it's on the ISFDb and was published in _Analog_. Haven't finished reading the story yet, but I guess it must be, then

Comment: I did a quick readthrough, and unfortunately, I don't think this one really fits the site. Cute story, though.

Comment: So, how's the poppa in danger here?

Comment: @Malady : He's not in danger in the excerpted passage.  At the risk of spoilers, Poppa gets in danger near the end when he's standing in a flooding cellar and tries to turn on the light but touches an empty (but live) socket instead.  The baby (actually a 4-year-old) saves him by shorting out all of the electricity in the house (which he has had prior experience with in this dangerously un-child-proofed home).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots :  It's fiction in which the plot hinges on a scientific concept (in this case, the nature of electric circuits).  It doesn't have to be trips to the stars to be science fiction.

Comment: It has to be a speculative scientific concept. Otherwise it is just regular mundane fiction, because *everything in our lives hinges on scientific concepts*. A lightly fictionalized novel about the life of Joe the Plumber is not science fiction just because it talks a lot about fluid flow and pressure. The fact that *The Big Bang Theory* has many episodes that hinge on the work of the main characters does not make it science fiction. *Numb3rs* is mostly about applied mathematics, but it is not science fiction.

Comment: There are any number of shows like *Bones* whose plots focus on the scientific methods used to solve crimes, but that does not make them science fiction, even if some of the science is a little out there. A story about astronauts who go to the moon in a rocket ship is not likely to be science fiction any more than a story about truck drivers who criss-cross the New World in automobiles would be.